# install4j log file i4j_log - Change log level

Tags: java, install4j

In our install4j Auto updater we are facing some problems and we are trying to find out more information from the log file i4j_log_xxx from the Users/Temp folder.

The contents inside this file start with the follwing log level [INFO]....

[INFO] logger started at Thu Nov 25 19:34:10 CET 2021

The question for me is how to change the log level from INFO to DEBUG?. Or is this even possible via arguments?. From the install4j documentation, I was not able to find any information on the log level changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change the log level. All messages are logged, their severity is displayed as [INFO] or [ERROR], but there is no filter.

Comment: Would it be possible to get more information out of the ERROR message?. e.g com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 1632]: Execute action
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_15
....................................
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 1632]: Execute action not successful after 3 ms -> A stacktrace (or) more information on why it has failed.

Comment: No, there is no additional information available, all information is logged.